# Blank Labels on form with Simple Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using simple form for my Application and i need to get rid of the labels but can't find a way.

I Tried: `<%= f.input :email, class: "login-field", label: "" %>` leaving the label blank, but this didn't work.

I'm relatively new to rails, could somebody explain how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `label:false` instead of `label:""`:

```
<%= f.input :email, class: "login-field", label: false %>
```